# I get the following error when running "npm start"

Tags: reactjs, npm

This is the error I get in PowerShell when I run: `npm start`.

I don't understand what `parsers` have to be `registered`.

```
PS D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx> npm start

> jsx@0.1.0 start D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.56.1/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx\node_modules\snapdragon\lib\parser.js:473
        throw new Error('no parsers registered for: "' + self.input.slice(0, 5) + '"');
        ^

Error: no parsers registered for: "] Fro"
    at parse (D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx\node_modules\snapdragon\lib\parser.js:473:15)
    at Parser.parse (D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx\node_modules\snapdragon\lib\parser.js:477:24)
    at Snapdragon.parse (D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx\node_modules\snapdragon\index.js:122:28)
    at Snapdragon.<anonymous> (D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx\node_modules\braces\lib\braces.js:40:45)
    at Braces.parse (D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx\node_modules\braces\lib\braces.js:66:26)
    at Braces.expand (D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx\node_modules\braces\lib\braces.js:87:18)
    at create (D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx\node_modules\braces\index.js:142:15)
    at memoize (D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx\node_modules\braces\index.js:298:13)
    at Function.braces.create (D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx\node_modules\braces\index.js:165:10)
    at Function.braces.expand (D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx\node_modules\braces\index.js:81:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! jsx@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the jsx@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LMALLIKARJUNAKE\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-21T14_29_11_835Z-debug.log
```

Comment: How did you set up your codebase in the first place? Have you run `npm install`?

Comment: @LukeStorry I have run `npm install -g create-react-app` and then `create-react-app jsx` before running the `npm start` command. This is my first day using these things.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the parser has a problem with the brackets (`[` and `]`) in your path, which is `D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx`.

Remove them (i.e., change the "name" of the directory) and also try to avoid spaces in the path. Modern OSs and most platforms/frameworks don't have a problem with it. But it often saves you trouble! :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I have just started, I did not get which **path** are you referring to, because I did not configure any path while installing npm. Is it the environment variable path??

Comment: Your path: `D:\Download\courses\Modern React with Redux [2020 Update]\MyReactWorkSpace\jsx\`

Comment: When coding, always try to avoid having any spaces or special characters in your folder or file names. That's why we use dashes or underscores. The square brackets, in particular, seem to be causing the problem.

Comment: Then please consider marking my answer as correct (or solution.. I don't know what it's called exactly -> green checkmark ;)
I adjusted my answer. Thanks @LukeStorry